# gem command -- can't download dependency seen on the remote repo

Tags: ruby, rubygems

If gem A shows as available on the remote repo, why would an install of gem B (which requires gem A) fail?  This has been working for a long time, but I can't see what has changed to cause this.

```
[root@ams01 agent]# /opt/sensu/embedded/bin/gem list pl_sensu_framework --remote --all

*** REMOTE GEMS ***

pl_sensu_framework (0.13.2, 0.13.1, 0.13.0, 0.12.12, 0.12.11, 0.12.10, 0.12.9, 0.12.8, 0.12.7, 0.12.6, 0.12.5, 0.12.4, 0.12.3, 0.12.2, 0.12.1, 0.12.0, 0.11.9, 0.11.8, 0.11.7, 0.11.6, 0.11.5, 0.11.4, 0.11.3, 0.11.2, 0.11.1, 0.11.0, 0.10.4, 0.10.3, 0.10.2, 0.10.1, 0.10.0, 0.9.3, 0.9.2, 0.9.1, 0.9.0, 0.1.3, 0.1.2, 0.1.1, 0.0.3, 0.0.2, 0.0.1)

[root@ams01 agent]# /opt/sensu/embedded/bin/gem install pl_sensu_agent
ERROR:  Error installing pl_sensu_agent:
    pl_sensu_agent requires pl_sensu_framework (= 0.13.2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to run:

> bundle uninstall pl_sensu_framework

and then try running

> bundle install pl_sensu_agent

Comment: These hosts are managed by Chef.  Bundler is not normally installed.  I set one up manually, but it didn't see the [un]install command.  

[root@ams01 agent]# /opt/sensu/embedded/bin/bundle uninstall pl_sensu_framework
Could not find command "uninstall".

Comment: Unfortunately i think I can't help you, I never worked with Chef. I have only seen this kind of problem with bundler and the method above solved it.

Good luck